# how to add page to wp plugin

Tags: wordpress

i'm creating a back-end WordPress plugin

and i want to add a second page but i don't want the second page to show-up  on the side dashboard.

i want it to look like this:

```
admin.php?page=pageX
```

i have tried this:

```
add_submenu_page('', 'Page X', '', 'manage_options', 'page-X', 'pagex_func');
```

it worked fine with a little problem the title doesn't show up
but i don't think that's **the right way** to do it.

Comment: You should not leave the page slug and the menu slug section empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `add_submenu_page()` directly and that's because you are calling the callback function very early even before WordPress has fully loaded. So you should call it like so.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' );
}
```

Please do refer to this documentation page on codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page#Example

Check out the example section.

Comment: thanks but with your code, it will show up under the tool section
and i said i don't want it to show up anywhere